# Some medias don't have oEmbeds from Instagram API

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to use [oEmbed](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/) from Instagram within my application but some medias aren't being loaded. Let me explain better, when I try to get the oEmbed from my last three photos it simply doesn't work, but it works with the other ones.

These doesn't work

https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BXlJl5aFHxy6di22JdoytQQj7hRszlugYYms7U0/

https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BXYZ65UF3gIdTs4vNyYbsjN1q5lkD09F8Atjr00/

https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BW8Ukn9lSDa9zRS_U6HD0D0Vyzv8cOIw0o3eVw0/

This one works

https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BRjqeNIDearnJzwXLJwz2C0svHTXcHGoKiQofo0/

Is there a reason for that? From the others developers it seems to work with every media including the first three ones. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why is because my profile wasn't public, turning it public solved my problem.